# Defining the deposit loop

Tags: python

When I run the code, the deposit loop gives me an error saying that i have not defined deposit. Does this have anything to do with the reading and writing to files? My code seems right so can someone please help? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
import time
import pickle
print("Hello, Welcome to Shawn's Bank ATM")
print("")
print("Please begin with creating an account")
name=input("Enter your name: ")
phone=input("Enter your phone number: ")
address=input("Enter your address: ")
code=input("Please enter a 4 digit pin to use as your passcode: ")

print()
print("Your account summary is:")
print("Name:" + name)
print("Phone Number:" + phone)     
print("Address:" + address)
print("Pin Code:" + code)    
print()

personalData = open("Personal data.txt","w")
personalData.write("Your name is " + name + "\n")
personalData.write("Your address is " + address + "\n")
personalData.write("Your phone number is " + phone + "\n")
personalData.write("Your password is " + code + "\n")           #the program will write the users information to a file, which can be called up by choosing one of the options
personalData.close()

history = open("History.txt","w")
history.close()                                                       #opens all files then closes them, easier to write to them when they are already made 
personalData_1 = open("Personal data Checking Account.txt","w")
personalData_1.close()
personalData_2 = open("Personal data Savings Account.txt","w")
personalData_2.close()

balance_1=float(input("Enter an amount to deposit into the savings account: "))
balance=float(input("Enter an amount to deposit into the chequing account: "))

print()
print(name,", Thank you for creating an account.")
def printMenu():
    print()
    print("Please choose an option below:")
    print("""
    Enter b to Check your Balance
    Enter d to Deposit money into your Account
    Enter w to Withdraw money from your Account
    Enter t to transfer money from chequing to savings
    Enter s to transfer money from savings to chequing
    Enter h to view your transaction history
    Enter q to Quit the Program """)
    print("")

def getTransaction():
    transaction=str(input("What would you like to do? "))
    return transaction

def withdraw_1(balance_1,amount):
    global balance
    balance=bal-amt
    if balance<0:
        balance=balance-10

def formatCurrency(amt):
    return "$%.2f" %amt

###MAIN PROGRAM###

printMenu()
command=str(getTransaction())

while command!="q":


    if (command=="b"):
        print(name,"Your current balance in your savings account is",formatCurrency(balance_1 ))
        print(name,"Your current balance in your chequing account is",formatCurrency(balance))
        printMenu()
        command=str(getTransaction())

    elif (command=="d"):      
        deposit=input("Press 1 for savings account//Press 2 for chequing account")
    if deposit=='1':
        amount=float(input("Amount to deposit into savings account? "))
        balance_1=balance_1+amount
        history = open("History.txt","w") 
        history.write(time.strftime("%c") + ": $" + (str(depositing) + " deposit into savings.\n"))
        history.close()
        printMenu()
        command=str(getTransaction())
    if deposit=='2':
        amount=float(input("Amount to deposit into chequing account? "))
        balance=balance+amount
        history = open("History.txt","w") 
        history.write(time.strftime("%c") + ": $" + (str(depositing) + " deposit into chequing.\n"))
        history.close()
        printMenu()
        command=str(getTransaction())

    elif (command=="w"):
        withdraw=input("Press 1 for savings account//Press 2 for chequing account")
        if withdraw=='1':
            amount=float(input("Amount to withdraw from savings account? "))
            withdraw_1(balance_1,amount)
            history = open("History.txt","w") 
            history.write(time.strftime("%c") + ": $" + (str(amount) + " withdrawal from savings.\n"))
            history.close()
        if withdraw=='2':
            amount=float(input("Amount to withdraw from chequing account? "))
            withdraw_1(balance,amount)
            history = open("History.txt","w") 
            history.write(time.strftime("%c") + ": $" + (str(amount) + " withdrawal from chequing.\n"))
            history.close()
            printMenu()
            command=str(getTransaction())

    elif (command=="h"):
        history = open("History.txt","r")
        print(history.read())
        history.close() 

    elif (command=="t"):
        transfer = float(input("Enter the amount you would like to transfer from your chequing account to your savings account ")) 
        balance_1 = balance - transfer
        print("Your balance in your savings account now is $", balance)
        print()
        print("Your balance in your Chequing Account now is $", balance)           #will take away money from checking account, and add to the savings account, will also write to the file aswell
        personalData_2 = open("Personal data Savings Account.txt","w")
        personalData_2.write("Your new balance is $" + (str(balance)))
        personalData_2.close()
        history = open("History.txt","w") 
        history.write(time.strftime("%c") + ": $" + (str(amount) + " has been transferred from chequing to savings account.\n"))
        history.close()
        printMenu()
        command=str(getTransaction())

    elif (command=="s"):
        transfer_1 = float(input("Enter the amount you would like to transfer from your Savings Account to Chequing Account "))
        balance_1 = balance + transfer_1
        print("Your balance in your checking account now is $", balance_1)
        print()                                                                       #will take away money from savings account, and add to the checking account, will also write to the file aswell
        print("Your balance in your Savings account now is $", balance) 
        personalData_1 = open("Personal data Checking Account.txt","w")
        personalData_1.write("Your new balance is $" + (str(balance))) 
        personalData_1.close()
        history = open("History.txt","w") 
        history.write(time.strftime("%c") + ": $" + (str(amount) + " has been transferred from savings to chequing account.\n"))
        history.close()
        printMenu()
        command=str(getTransaction())


else:
        print("Incorrect command. Please try again.")
        printMenu()
        command=str(getTransaction())



print(name,"Goodbye! See you again soon")
```

Comment: your indentation for your deposit if statements are wrong

Comment: seriously? can u show me how to correctly indent it? thanks

Comment: there is no "deposit loop" in your code.

Comment: i meant statement..sorry

Comment: look at the way you indented your `withdraw` block, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

You check for balance or deposit, but then you check what the deposit choice was (savings or checking) regardless of whether the user actually selected "deposit." Indent the relevant blocks so that they only occur when the user selects "deposit":

```
elif (command=="d"):      
    deposit=input("Press 1 for savings account//Press 2 for chequing account")
    if deposit=='1':
        ...
    elif deposit=='2':
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using deposit as an integer, but you've never defined the object before it is being referenced (at the start of your project.)

```
 deposit = 0
```